# I need some answers for solving these problems.I am stuck in these errors whilw programming in Ada using records

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada programming.This is my ADA CODE for a program which gives me a list of things when typed a Football legend name in execution time.But I am getting the following errors.Please help me out:

Some of the Errors found are:
1.Discriminants must have a discrete or Access type
2.components "FBClubs cannot be used before end of record declaration
3.discriminant in a variant part must be of discrete part
4."player" is undefined 
5."pos" is undefined.
6.no candidate interpretations match the sctuals : = > in call to inherited operation "to_string" at line "type playernames..."

```
with Ada.Text_Io; use Ada.Text_Io; 
with Ada.Integer_Text_Io; use Ada.Integer_Text_Io; 
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

Procedure football_record is 
type Position is (Goalkeeper,Midfielder,Forward,Defender);
type playernames is new Unbounded_String;
type FBClubs is (ACMilan,Man_United,Aresnal,ParisSt.Germain,Real_Madrid,Liverpool,Chelsea,Man_City,Lille,
Tottenham,Ajax,Juventus,Dortmund,Roma,Santos,Roma,Bayern_Munich,Inter_Milan);
type countries is (England,Argentina,Brazil,France,Italy,Portugal,Spain,Germany,Iran,Japan);
type fbplayer(player:playernames) is 
   record 
WCAppearances:Integer;
pos:Position;
country:countries;
fbclubs:FBClubs;
case player is 
 when "David Beckham" =>
        country:countries:=England;
        WCAppearances:Integer:=3;
        pos:Position:=Midfielder;
        fbclubs:FBClubs:=ACMilan &"+" & Man_United &"+" & Real_Madrid &"+"& ParisSt.Germain;
 when "Lionel Messi" =>
        country:countries:=Argentina;
        WCAppearances:Integer:=1;
        pos:Position:=Forward;
        fbclubs:FBClubs:=Barcelona;
.....and some other 12 players(legends)..
when others =>
       country:countries:=Nil;
       WCAppearances:Integer:=Nil;
       pos:Position:=Nil;
       fbclubs:FBClubs:=Nil;
end case; 
end record; 

begin
Get(player);
Put_Line(To_String(Integer'Image(player)));
Put_Line(To_String(Integer'Image(FBClubs'Image(fbclubs)));
Put_Line(To_Unbounded_String(Position'Image(pos)));
end football_record;
```

Comment: `fbclubs:FBClubs;` is one of your problems : as Ada is not case-sensitive you have simply repeated the same identifier twice. One of them (the type or the variable) should be different...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I changed the names.But I am worried about how to declare footballer name in the run time? and according to the name typed of the football player,I need to get all the info like country,WCAppearances,pos and clubs.

Comment: Next, as the error says, you can't use Strings (yet alone Unbounded Strings) as discriminants. Redesign the solution so you don't need to.

Comment: Why do you use a variant record (`type fbplayer(player:playernames) is ...`) instead of having `player` as a simple component of `fbplayer`?

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem is that you're mixing code in with a type declaration.

In Ada, putting a `case` within a `record` is only for *variant* records; these are records where some fields exist in certain cases but not others.  For example:

```
type Employee_Type is (Regular, Manager);
type Employee (Emp_Type : Employee_Type) is record
     Name : Unbounded_String;
     case Emp_Type is
         when Manager =>
              Managerial_Level : Integer;
         when Regular =>
              null;
     end case;
end record;
```

This is a variant record; we're assuming here that there are two kinds of employees, and the `Managerial_Level` field makes sense only for one of those kinds.  Records whose type is `Regular` will not have a `Managerial_Level` field at all.

This syntax isn't what you would use to return different *values* of fields.  Instead, you need to do this in *statements*, usually in a `procedure` or `function` (or package initialization, or some other places that allow statements).

And since you're not using the variant record syntax, you don't need to make `player` a discriminant.  It doesn't work, anyway; in Ada, a "discriminant" (like `Emp_Type` in my example) has to be a discrete type like an integer or an enumeration type (`Employee_Type` is an enumeration type), or an access (access discriminants are an advanced concept).  It can't be an `Unbounded_String`.  So you'd want to make `player` a regular field:

```
type fbplayer is record
    player : Unbounded_String;
    pos : Position;
    country : countries;
    clubs : FBClubs;   -- Note name change!
    WCAppearances : Integer;
end record;
```

and create a procedure to fill in the fields:

```
procedure Fill_In_Player(P : in out fbplayer; Player : Playernames) is
begin
    P.Player := Player;
    if Player = "David Beckham" then
        P.country := England;
        P.WCAppearances := 3;
        P.pos = Midfielder;
        P.clubs := ??? -- see below
    elsif Player = "Lionel Messi" then
        ------- etc.
    elsif ------
    end if;
end Fill_In_Player;
```

and then call `Fill_In_Player` when you have the `Player` and want to set up the record fields.  You have to write *statements* to do this; you can't do it inside the declaration of a record.

Note that in Ada, `case` statements can only be used on integer or enumeration types.  You can't use them to test for a string, as some other languages allow.

Ada treats lower-case and upper-case letters the same in identifiers or keywords.  Therefore, `fbclubs` is the same name as `FBClubs`, and you can't declare the field

```
fbclubs : FBClubs;
```

because of the name conflict.  I changed the name.

Finally, it looks like you want `FBClubs` to hold more than one club.  But `FBClubs` is an enumeration type, and can therefore hold only one value at a time.  If you want each player record to contain a list of clubs, you'll need to do something else, such as using one of Ada's container types (like `Ada.Containers.Vectors.Vector`) or something like

```
type Set_Of_Clubs is array(FBClubs) of Boolean;
```

where each array value is `true` if the player played for that club.

I'm not sure that will take care of all your errors, but it looks like you have a lot of work to do already.